# Needed to delete and relink fonts. Now iOS won't relink the fonts

Tags: react-native

I have a React Native app that I added custom fonts to, and I messed up naming, so I had to delete them. I deleted them from the info.plist and the build phases portion of Xcode, and from what I read online you just re-add the fonts and run `npx react-native link` again to get them back. However, I *cannot* get the fonts to be recognized any more. They don't show up in XCode any more either. How do I 'reset' the custom fonts in my folder?

To be clear - The first time I did it they showed up and worked, but I needed to change the naming so I deleted them (per a post I saw online). So the process *does* work - It just doesn't any more.

Structure `/app/src/assets/fonts/[fonts here]`
react-native.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  assets: [
    './src/assets/fonts'
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In xcode, check the resources folder and delete everything in there. [image: Resources in xcode]